# Workflow outboundmessage not working when updating data using data loader

Tags: workflow, data-loader

I have a workflow outbound message on opportunity which works when I am updating a single record manually. But when I am updating bulk records via data loader the same OM is not working. I can see the the OMs in the delivery queue but still they are not processing. What could be the problem?

Comment: Is your message consumer capable of handling such high volumes? Or is it pushing back causing the OM queue to back up ?

Comment: Have any of them failed or is it just sat there awaiting sending?

Comment: @techtrekker Yes it can handle high volumes.

Comment: @pbattisson None of them failed. I refreshed the monitoring page and the queue was empty without any error message.

Comment: see this for more info http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/workflow-outbound-message-lost