# Outbound Messages won't send from Workflow Rule

Tags: workflow, workflowoutboundmessage

I have a Workflow Rule set up to send an Outbound Message every time a Lead is edited. We evaluate the rule when a record is: "created, and every time it's edited". The Rule Criteria is set to Field: *Lead:Zip Code*, Operator: *not equal to*, Value: *00000* (I want this rule to fire an outbound message each and every time a Lead is edited).

The Outbound Message is pretty standard. Just hits our endpoint URL and "Send Session ID" box is ticked. We are just sending the Id.

After I activate this rule and try to test it by editing a lead, we never see our URL getting hit.

When I check the delivery status in Outbound Messages>View Message Delivery Status, there are no messages at all.

I have searched for an answer, and while there are good questions and answers about [Outbound Messages being lost](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1961/workflow-outbound-message-lost), ours are not lost, they appear to never send in the first place.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

UPDATE - Here is the log from the Developer Console. It appears that the rule requirements are met and the message fired.
[image]

UPDATE SOLVED - Getting the message to fire every time with NOT(ISBLANK(Name)) worked great. We also had a issue with the URL we were hitting silently failing. Best thing was seeing the workings in the Developers Console. That was a great tip.

Comment: Did you activate the rule?

Comment: Yep Activated the Rule. Spent around 10 mins head scratching before I thought of that. But once I activated it, nothing still.

Comment: Try change criteria to for example NOT(ISBLANK(Name)).
Then open debug, update record and check debug log. If it still won't work please provide us with this log

Comment: Went to Setup>Monitor>Logs>Debug Logs and there is nothing there. I also went to the Developer Console. My WF_CRITERIA_END evaluates to True on the Last Name not being blank. I'll post the log.

Comment: Messages are going thru. Thanks for all the help. I will update my q with info we found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets do some guess here:

1) Do you have all as per this doc : https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_setting_up.htm

There is a line that says "

> If you do not have these options, your organization does not have
>   outbound messaging enabled. Contact salesforce.com to enable outbound
>   messaging for your organization.

" 
so I have a feeling that outbound message needs to be activated for your org. ( I could be wrong here since you seem to have setup everything, just writing this since it might be a good reference for others to follow)

2) As per Daniel's blog :

http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/08/salesforce-outbound-messages-not-being.html

It looks like the user needs to have

Administrative Permissions: Send Outbound Messages

check if this is enabled on the user profile. If you are sending it as a sys admin ( beware I have seen orgs cloning standard profiles and renaming to create a custom profile, so if you are standard sys admin and not a custom one)   you should have it by default.

Comment: @joshuaDance what solved your issue, was it the permission/ org was not enabled with outbound message. It would be helpful if you can point that out for site visitors if they are struck with the same issue.

Comment: Great idea @rao. Done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare's `browser integrity check` could cause the issue.

So if you use cloudflare for your endpoint, make sure to turn that setting off.